# iOS parse and int from a text box and assign it to an integer value to be used in a sum?

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing

Sorry I realise this is a simple question but im new to iOS development and objective-c.

Coming from a c# background, I would try parse the string in the text box then if true assign it to an int to be used in a sum, then assign that to a label.

In iOS and obj-c im having some trouble with the above, and then what I would need to release and alloc.

Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do that. For example:

```
NSString *test = @"45";
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:test];
NSInteger integer;
if ([scanner scanInteger:&integer])
{
    NSLog(@"The value is: %i", integer);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Didn't parse successfully.");
}
```

As another answer notes, you can use `intValue` or `integerValue` on `NSString`. There are a couple of things to note about that approach:

1. It returns 0 if the parse fails. This makes it impossible to determine if the value parsed was actually 0, or if the parse just failed.
2. Both `NSScanner` and `intValue` allow for whitespace, so     `45` would parse successfully. With NSScanner, you can disable that if you desire by using `setCharactersToBeSkipped` to nil:

   ```
   [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
   ```

You can perform normal arithmetic from there on, like `integer + 20`, or sum other numbers that you've parsed.

If locale is important (See [Julien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818099/492405)), then you would use the `setLocale` method on NSScanner with an [`NSLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for example, if we want to ensure the en-US locale is always used:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[scanner setLocale: locale];
```

---

> what I would need to release and alloc.

That depends on quite a few things. Are you using ARC? If so then ARC will take care of the release for you.  You may want to [read up](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) on memory management.

Comment: Don't forget to set the `NSScanner`'s locale here.

Answer (score 2):

To get a string from a UITextField (assuming *textField is your UITextField)

```
int integetValue=[textField.text intValue];
```

Then you can sum it just like normal ints. To set this value to UILabel you need to do( assuming sum is your integer summary ):

```
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sum]];
```

In this case you wont need to alloc/release anything.

Comment: Note that these examples don't respect the user's locale. From `NSString`'s documentation: "[These methods use] formatting information stored in the non-localized value; use an NSScanner object for localized scanning of numeric values from a string."

Answer (score 1):

It depends how "international" your string is.

If you are manipulating low level formatted numbers (i.e. you are completely ignoring the user's locale), you can use `-[NSString intValue]` (or similar methods) or `-[NSScanner initWithString:]` to convert a string to a number. And you can use `"%d"` formatting specifier (and other formatting specifiers) to convert a number to a string.

However, you likely want to respect the user's locale, where decimal separator can be a dot, or a comma, where digits themselves can use a different character set than the usual "arabic digits".

In this case, you want to use `NSNumberFormatter` or set up `NSScanner`'s locale.

Note that chosing which locale you want to interpret the numbers with all depends on where the string comes from (or goes to).